# $(x,y)$ points extrapolation

Tags: interpolation, extrapolation

My process is generating $x,y$ points. The points are result of tracking movement of an object so its a bit inertial. The tracked object can't change direction rapidly. I need to extrapolate data between 2 points. I have an advantage that I know points before missing points and after missing points. There is a picture for a better understanding. Dotted line need to be extrapolated and I know how many points are missing.
[image]

Comment: One method that will give a smooth curve is making a [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) of the points you got and using the results to get the missing points (for example a [qubic spline](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html)).